# Internal Server Error while uploading wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

## Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@karupayi.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

tried to upload wordpress theme... got this error.... but in other server i can upload this theme successfully

Comment: Enable error config in wp_config.php file

Comment: Try reaching out to hosting provider if you can’t solve the issue.